# Redux Saga: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

dispatching action with payload, produces this typescript error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel'.
```

Example:

```
export default function* watchAuth() {
yield* takeLatest(startAuth.toString(), handleAuthUser); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel'.
}
```

using:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
"typed-redux-saga": "^1.5.0",
```

Edit: handleAuthUser generator function

```
function* handleAuthUser({ payload: { fields, isRegister } }) {
  const { email, password } = fields || {};
  try {
    if (isRegister) {
      // User registering an account
      yield* call(registerAWS, fields);
      yield* put(promptConfirmation({ email, password }));
    } else {
      // User is logging into his account
      const cognitoUser = yield* call(newCognitoUser, email);

      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: email,
        Password: password,
      });

      const res = yield* call(loginAWS, cognitoUser, authDetails);
      if (res.userAttributes) {
        const { email_verified, phone_number_verified, ...userAttributes } = res.userAttributes;
        yield* put(
          promptNewPassword({
            email,
            userAttributes,
            cognitoUser,
          }),
        );
      } else {
        yield* put(checkAuth());
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    switch ((error as any).code) {
      // switch cases
    }
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
startAuth: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ fields: { [key: string]: string }; isRegister?: boolean }>,
    ) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.errors = { login: {}, signup: {}, other: {} };
      state.userPendingConfirmation = null;
      state.userPendingNewPassword = null;
      state.resetPasswordUser = null;
    },
```

Comment: Can you share definition of `handleAuthUser` ?

Comment: Error does come from `takeLatest()` expecting an object of type `TakeableChannel` but receiving a `string` from `startAuth.toString()`. Can you provide `takeLatest`defintion ?

Comment: @IQbrod https://github.com/agiledigital/typed-redux-saga/blob/master/types/index.d.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to modify the types of `handleAuthUser`. The issue is that `takeLatest` expects that first parameter of the saga that is going to be run (handleAuthUser) to be an object with a `type` property, but the way you have it defined now typescript assumes `payload` is the only property of that object, which doesn't match the expectation.

So changing it to:

```js
type AnyAction = {type: string, [key: string]: any}
function* handleAuthUser({ payload: { fields, isRegister } }: AnyAction) {
```

will fix it since you are telling TS that the object has among other action params also the `type` property.

Comment: I totally forgot that I had another redux slice, where I had the same issue and I solved it by importing PayloadAction from '@reduxjs/toolkit' and passing the payload object definition, same as the reducer.

Thanks to you I remembered!

Comment: function* handleAuthUser({
  payload: { fields, isRegister },
}: PayloadAction<{ fields: { [key: string]: string }; isRegister?: boolean }>) {